# How to recover Script file in visual studio 2019?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, data-recovery

I was working on mvc core web app in visual studio 2019 and there was an electricity failure and my pc becomes off. After turn on pc my script file is not opening in visual studio 2019

[image]

Files contains only white spaces and all my today's work is lost. Is there any way to recover code in 
js file ?

Comment: Did you make sure to save often enough?

Comment: Yes i have saved my code before electricity off

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no code was lost

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me during a similar situation:

1. Open the location of the script file (project folder)
2. See if there is any `.tmp` file, containing the contents of your script
3. Paste the content to a new file and save it as a new script.

Comment: Hey OMITF, Welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not only meant to answer specific questions to a user, but also for everybody else on the internet to learn from other's questions and answers. In that regard, it would be better to formulate your answer more formal next time, so without the details about the weather and only including the information answering the core problem. Read up in the article [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)